# Developing Windows service using WCF

Tags: wcf

I have one requirement. 
In our company each employee will submit some standard reports using internal portal.
If some employees not submitted report end of the day manager should get notified list of employees not submitted report.
I am using SQL Server database in which one table maintains records the employees submitting reports.
For this i want to use WCF client service.

This service will be installed on the server and client service should send email to Manager at specific time whoever not filled reports.

I know this is very basic requirement and i can do in Windows service. But I want to implement using WCF client service.
Can anyone help me how to do this task using WCF. And can you please refer some links.

Comment: I don't see how WCF fits in here. You want a plain program working on a schedule. That can be achieved by a ConsoleApplication and Windows Scheduler or a windows service that does it all by itself. But WCF just does not fit in. WCF is for communication and there is no communication. The program works on a schedule without being communicated with.

Comment: The **Windows service** is a piece of software that can run on a server without any user even being logged in. It has **nothing to do** with communications, however! The **WCF Service** on the other hand is a communcations service - it has **nothing** to do with running at startup time. You can *host* your WCF service inside a Windows service - but you cannot *write your Windows service using WCF* - those are two totally different things

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to host the wcf service in windows service instead of IIS.

```
var serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(YourService));
serviceHost.Open()
```

Open the service host in the onstart method of windows serice and close on onstop event. And copy the wcf config from wcf service project to windows service project and comment the configuration from wcf service project.